# Graphic display of tables

Tags: r, console

I hope this is not a too silly question, but I feel that sometimes it would really be much nicer to view the columns of a table centered in R-console... At the moment, the data (read in from csv file) is bound to the right. Is there a way to adjust this?

Comment: This sounds like you probably want to look at the `justify` argument of `print`. I don't think centering is possible, though.